# Log Parser2.2 TO_DATE & TO_TIMESTAMP conversion

Tags: timestamp, logparser

Just started using log parser 2.2, so please excuse me if this is too silly, but I am stuck at converting a string to timestamp.

The following Query gives me an output of the date in string format from a log file

```
$>logparser -i:textline -RTP:-1 "SELECT TOP 1 EXTRACT_SUFFIX(text,0,'TIMESTAMP') from 'C:\ptclmgrd.log' where text like '%TIMESTAMP%'"

EXTRACT_SUFFIX(Text, 0, 'TIMESTAMP')
------------------------------------
 2/6/2015

Statistics:
-----------
Elements processed: 951
Elements output:    1
Execution time:     0.03 seconds
```

I need to insert the above string in csv, or table but it should be in date format.

If I try the following, the output is just `-`:

```
$>logparser -i:textline -RTP:-1 "SELECT TOP 1 TO_TIMESTAMP(EXTRACT_SUFFIX(text,0,'TIMESTAMP'),'MM/dd/yyyy') from 'C:\ptclmgrd.log' where text like '%TIMESTAMP%'"

TO_TIMESTAMP(EXTRACT_SUFFIX(Text, 0, 'TIMESTAMP'), 'MM/dd/yyyy')
----------------------------------------------------------------
-

Statistics:
-----------
Elements processed: 951
Elements output:    1
Execution time:     0.01 seconds
```

The log file entry that I am trying to parse is something like:

```
3:12:40 (lmgrd) TIMESTAMP 2/6/2015
```

Any idea what's wrong? I am expecting the output as same string in date format.
I also tried `M/d/YYYY` but getting same output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with lower-case 'y':

```
M/d/yyyy
```

Here is a description of the timestamp elements:

```
y       1-digit year
yy      2-digit year
yyy     3-digit year
yyyy    4-digit year
M       month as digit without leading zeros
MM      month as digit with leading zeros
MMM     month as 3-character abbreviation of month name
MMMM    month as full month name
d       day as digit without leading zeros
dd      day as digit with leading zeros
ddd     day as 3-character abbreviation of day name
dddd    day as full day name
h,H     hour without leading zeros
hh,HH   hour with leading zeros
m       minutes without leading zeros
mm      minutes with leading zeros
s       seconds without leading zeros
ss      seconds with leading zeros
```

Comment: Thanks Gabriele . But the output i get is simple - (dash). I was expecting date. i also tried the following:  logparser -i:textline -RTP:-1 "SELECT TOP 1 TO_DATE(TO_TIMESTAMP(EXTRACT_SUFFIX(text,0,'TIMESTAMP'),'M/d/yyyy')) from 'C:\ptclmgrd.log' where text like '%TIMESTAMP%'"  but i just get the output as -

Comment: Can you post the output of "SELECT EXTRACT_SUFFIX(text,0,'TIMESTAMP'), TO_TIMESTAMP(EXTRACT_SUFFIX(text,0,'TIMESTAMP'),'M/d/yyyy') FROM ..."?

Comment: Following is the output:EXTRACT_SUFFIX(Text, 0, 'TIMESTAMP') TO_TIMESTAMP(EXTRACT_SUFFIX(Text, 0, 'TIMESTAMP'), 'M/d/yyyy')
------------------------------------ --------------------------------------------------------------
 2/6/2015                            -

Comment: Ok, it's clear that the result of EXTRACT_SUFFIX has a leading space. Use TRIM() on it in the TO_TIMESTAMP call.

Comment: Gabriele , That was amazing solution !!  Worked like charm !!!  Many thanks for your help. I was stuck with this for such a long time and could not get the idea of the Whitespace leading character....